# Solace JCA using JBoss JNDI

Tags: solace

The JCA resource adapter uses Solace as a JNDI store for fetching connection and destinations. We are looking at an option where Solace JNDI option is disabled at the broker but the application needs to be fetch the connection factory/destinations using JNDI lookup in JBOSS server. Is this feasible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature will be available in the upcoming release of the Solace JMS Resource Adapter. In this release, there will be the option to configure your application to use a non-Solace JNDI store. This can be done by setting the JNDI provider's (in your case, JBoss) Connection URL, username, and password in the Resource Adapter's bean properties.